# Line Integral Problem - Theoretically Should Be Simple

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate $\int_C P(x,y)dx + \int_CQ(x,y)dy$ where $P(x,y) = y^2, Q(x,y) = x$, C is the part of the graph $x=y^3$ from $(-1,-1)$ to $(1,1)$.

So, I begin by parametrizing: $x=t, y=t^3$, which makes my integral take on the limits $\int_{-1}^{1}$.

Starting at $\int_C P(x,y)dx$, I end up with the integral $\int_{a}^{b} y^2x(t)'dt$, which parametrizes to $\int_{-1}^{1}(t^3)^2 dt$. The final answer I get is $\frac{2}{7}$. Following a similar procedure for $\int_C Q(x,y)dy$, I get an answer for that part of $0$. This makes my final answer $\frac{2}{7}$, while the one provided in the book is $\frac{6}{5}$. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your parametrisation must be $y=t$ and $x=t^{3}$! The curve will hence be $r(t) = (t^{3},t)$ and you want to find the work of the vector field (t^{2},t^{3}). Hence the integral $\int\limits{-1}^{1} (t^{2},t^{3}) \cdot (3t^{2},1) dt = \int\limits_{-1}^{1} 3t^{4}dt=\frac{6}{5}$

Comment: Oh my god... did I just do that?

Comment: Just checked, and yep, that was it. I made that mistake over and over. Thank you!